How do I replace a folder of photos on Mac Photo with a new photos
In Finder, I modified the original image file name to be more descriptive. Now I want to re-import it into Photo. But Photo won't use the new file name in the photo information. It will import the new file but uses the original file name. I want the new file name on Photo because it is more descriptive.

You can modify file names etc directly in Photos.
